# html5 to get filepath from a browser

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking to pull the absolute filepath in a browser. For example, if someone selects a word document on their Desktop, it would show:

```
/Users/tom/Desktop
```

Is have heard that this is possible using html5. Could someone please describe how this is done or provide a link to documentation?

Comment: [HTML5 file api](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) should get you going.

Comment: Did you search this place before you posted it? It is asked 100s of times.